# Only one processor being used while running NetLogo models using parApply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, netlogo

I am using the 'RNetLogo' package to run sensitivity analyses on my NetLogo model. My model has 24 parameters I need to vary - so parallelising this process would be ideal! I've been following along with the example in Thiele's "[Parallel processing with the RNetLogo package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RNetLogo/vignettes/parallelProcessing.pdf)" vignette, which uses the 'parallel' package in conjunction with 'RNetLogo'.

I've managed to get R to initialise the NetLogo model across all 12 of my processors, which I've verified using gui=TRUE. The problem comes when I try to run the simulation code across the 12 processors using 'parApply'. This line runs without error, but it only runs on one of the processors (using around 8% of my total CPU power). Here's a mock up of my R code file - I've included some commented-out code at the end, showing how I run the simulation without trying to parallelise:

```
### Load packages
library(parallel)

### Set up initialisation function
prepro <- function(dummy, gui, nl.path, model.path) {
          library(RNetLogo)
          NLStart(nl.path, gui=gui)
          NLLoadModel(model.path)
}

### Set up finalisation function
postpro <- function(x) {
           NLQuit()
}

### Set paths
# For NetLogo
nl.path <- "C:/Program Files/NetLogo 6.0/app"
nl.jarname <- "netlogo-6.0.0.jar"
# For the model
model.path <- "E:/Model.nlogo"
# For the function "sim" code
sim.path <- "E:/sim.R"

### Set base values for parameters
base.param <- c('prey-max-velocity'                  = 25,
                'prey-agility'                       = 3.5,
                'prey-acceleration'                  = 20,
                'prey-deceleration'                  = 25,
                'prey-vision-distance'               = 10,
                'prey-vision-angle'                  = 240,
                'time-to-turn'                       = 5,
                'time-to-return-to-foraging'         = 300,
                'time-spent-circling'                = 2,
                'predator-max-velocity'              = 35,
                'predator-agility'                   = 3.5,
                'predator-acceleration'              = 20,
                'predator-deceleration'              = 25,
                'predator-vision-distance'           = 20,
                'predator-vision-angle'              = 200,
                'time-to-give-up'                    = 120,
                'number-of-safe-zones'               = 1,
                'number-of-target-patches'           = 5,
                'proportion-obstacles'               = 0.05,
                'obstacle-radius'                    = 2.0,
                'obstacle-radius-range'              = 0.5,
                'obstacle-sensitivity-for-prey'      = 0.95,
                'obstacle-sensitivity-for-predators' = 0.95,
                'safe-zone-attractiveness'           = 500
)

## Get names of parameters
param.names <- names(base.param)

### Load the code of the simulation function (name: sim)
source(file=sim.path)

### Convert "base.param" to a matrix, as required by parApply
base.param <- matrix(base.param, nrow=1, ncol=24)

### Get the number of simulations we want to run
design.combinations <- length(base.param[[1]])
already.processed <- 0

### Initialise NetLogo
processors <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(processors)
clusterExport(cl, 'sim')
gui <- FALSE
invisible(parLapply(cl, 1:processors, prepro, gui=gui, nl.path=nl.path, model.path=model.path))

### Run the simulation across all processors, using parApply
sim.result.base <- parApply(cl, base.param, 1, sim,
                            param.names, 
                            no.repeated.sim = 100,
                            trace.progress = FALSE, 
                            iter.length = design.combinations, 
                            function.name = "base parameters")

### Run the simulation on a single processor
#sim.result.base <- sim(base.param, 
#                       param.names, 
#                       no.repeated.sim = 100, 
#                       my.nl1, 
#                       trace.progress = TRUE, 
#                       iter.length = design.combinations, 
#                       function.name = "base parameters")
```

Here's a mock up for the 'sim' function (adapted from Thiele's paper "Facilitating parameter estimation and sensitivity analyses of agent-based models - a cookbook using NetLogo and R"):

```
sim <- function(param.set, parameter.names, no.repeated.sim, trace.progress, iter.length, function.name) {

  # Some security checks
  if (length(param.set) != length(parameter.names))
  { stop("Wrong length of param.set!") }
  if (no.repeated.sim <= 0)
  { stop("Number of repetitions must be > 0!") }
  if (length(parameter.names) <= 0)
  { stop("Length of parameter.names must be > 0!") }

   # Create an empty list to save the simulation results
   eval.values <- NULL

   # Run the repeated simulations (to control stochasticity)
   for (i in 1:no.repeated.sim)
   {
     # Create a random-seed for NetLogo from R, based on min/max of NetLogo's random seed
     NLCommand("random-seed",runif(1,-2147483648,2147483647))

     ## This is the stuff for one simulation
     cal.crit <- NULL

     # Set NetLogo parameters to current parameter values
     lapply(seq(1:length(parameter.names)), function(x) {NLCommand("set ",parameter.names[x], param.set[x])})
     NLCommand("setup")
     # This should run "go" until prey-win =/= 5, i.e. when the pursuit ends
     NLDoCommandWhile("prey-win = 5", "go")

     # Report a value
     prey <- NLReport("prey-win")
     # Report another value
     pred <- NLReport("predator-win")

     ## Extract the values we are interested in
     cal.crit <- rbind(cal.crit, c(prey, pred))

     # append to former results
     eval.values <- rbind(eval.values,cal.crit)
   }

   ## Make sure eval.values has column names
   names(eval.values) <- c("PreySuccess", "PredSuccess")

   # Return the mean of the repeated simulation results
   if (no.repeated.sim > 1) {
     return(colMeans(eval.values))
   }
   else {
     return(eval.values)
   }
}
```

I think the problem might lie in the "nl.obj"  string that RNetLogo uses to identify the NetLogo instance you want to run the code on - however, I've tried several different methods of fixing this, and I haven't been able to come up with a solution that works. When I initialise NetLogo across all the processors using the code provided in Thiele's example, I don't set an "nl.obj" value for each instance, so I'm guessing RNetLogo uses some kind of default list? However, in Thiele's original code, the "sim" function requires you to specify which NetLogo instance you want to run it on - so R will spit an error when I try to run the final line (Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : one node produced an error: argument "nl.obj" is missing, with no default). I have modified the "sim" function code so that it doesn't require this argument and just accepts the default setting for nl.obj - but then my simulation only runs on a single processor. So, I think that by default, "sim" must only be running the code on a single instance of NetLogo. I'm not certain how to fix it.

This is also the first time I've used the 'parallel' package, so I could be missing something obvious to do with 'parApply'. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still in the process of applying a similar technique to perform a Morris Elementary Effects screening with my NetLogo model. For me the parallel execution works fine. I compared your script to mine and noticed that in my version the 'parApply' call of the simulation function (simfun) is embedded in a function statement (see below). Maybe including the function already solves your issue.

```
  sim.results.morris <- parApply(cl, mo$X, 1, function(x) {simfun(param.set=x, 
                                                           no.repeated.sim=no.repeated.sim, 
                                                           parameter.names=input.names, 
                                                           iter.length=iter.length, 
                                                           fixed.values=fixed.values, 
                                                           model.seed=new.model.seed, 
                                                           function.name="Morris")})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tyr! I tried modifying my code to match up with your example, but I get the error: 'Error in parApply(cl, base.param, 1, function(x) { : dim(X) must have a positive length'. But when I check the length of X (which I'm assuming is base.param), it's 24. Did you encounter this at all?

Comment: Woops, scratch that @Tyr, I fixed it (rearranged a few things and forgot to convert to a matrix). The code runs fine, but unfortunately the problem is still there - it's only using one processor. If the same code works across processors for you, I wonder if there's something I need to override in R to force it to use more than one processor? Hmmm.

Comment: ahh. Right. base.param has to be a matrix. I checked your code again and looked at the construction of your parameter matrix. Is it true that in your matrix you have only one experiment, i.e. one row in your matrix? That would explain why only one core is used, because there is only one experiment. Parallelisation only works if you have multiple rows in your parameter matrix. Then each row is simulated by another core.

Comment: However, for a proper sensitivity analysis you have to vary at least one of your parameters. For instance, if you are interested in the local effect of 'prey-max-velocity' your matrix has to have multiple rows where all parameters stay constant except 'prey-max-velocity' which is varied systematically or randomly. For a global sensitivity analysis I can really recommend the Morris Screening for a first look on parameter effects. Guidelines on implementation can be found here (http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/17/3/11.html). I hope that helps?

Comment: Oh wow, it works!! The code I posted above isn't actually the code for my sensitivity analysis - I encountered the problem with the single core when I was trying to parallelise my Sobol analyses, so I backtracked and have been trying to get it to work with some simpler code - above is just running 100 sims of the same experiment/row to get the result from my base parameter values. I just tried it varying a single parameter (multiple experiments/rows) - and it works perfectly! I misinterpreted how parApply partitioned the sims, but that makes sense now. Thanks so much! =)